# Microsoft Access Form not updating

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table that has 3 columns - Unique #, State of Program, and State of Mailing. 
(It can have more than 1 of same state)
I created a form where I use the dropdown to Select the state and the form will display the State of Program and State of Mailing.

So for example -
If I select CA & CA, the form will display the correct fields. But then once I select CA & MD, the form will be just stuck at CA & CA. If I continue to select IL & IL, the form will update again. And if I select IL & IN, the form gets stuck again...

Can anyone help???!!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I assigned the wrong ID in the dropdown menu.
Problem solved.